# Passing variables from sh into sql

Tags: sql, bash, shell

```
declare -a array[2]
for  (( i=0; i<3; i++ ))
do
read array[$i]
done

for  (( n=0; n<3; n++ ))
do
echo  -e "From Table[$n]: ${array[$n]}\n " ;
done

sqlplus owner/pass@db << ENDOFSQL
    @file.sql
exit;
ENDOFSQL;
```

I Need to use the bash array[] variables in the file.sql script.

Comment: Sample input/output needed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `file.sql` from the input, you don't need an array. You can read and write in the same for loop

```
for (( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )); do
    read a
    echo "From Table[$i]: $a"
done >file.sql
```

this will create `file.sql`, which you can then pass to sqlplus

```
sqlplus owner/pass@db @file.sql
```

You should also be able to skip the input file altogether and pipe the output of the for loop directly to sqlplus

```
for (( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )); do
    read a
    echo "From Table[$i]: $a"
done | sqlplus owner/pass@db
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How to pass then the file to sqlplus / plsql?

Comment: @Dave According to http://serverfault.com/q/87035, you can just give it on the command line as `sqlplus ... @file.sql`. I updated my answer accordingly.